# How to display image from mongodb using Reactjs

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, react-redux

I've saved my image in Mongodb like that :

```
 "img": {
    "data": "<Binary Data>",
    "contentType": "image/png"
}
```

I try to display it in ReactJS  using this code :

```
..{products.map(product => {
   <img src= {product.img} />
```

But nothing is displayed. Any idea  please to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to display your image in src attribute with binary data when it expect an url.

If it's binary data you need to diplay it like this and tell to your component that you are passing binary data

```
<img src={`data:image/png;base64,${product.img.data}`} />
```

Comment: I get this error :    ` Syntax error: JSX value should be either an expression or a quoted JSX text (93:60)`

Comment: Try this new version. Also be sure to check how your binary data is formatted. Maybe it already have base64, or data:image/png;base64, so you need to adapt it. If you can give me an example of your binary data i can give you exactly what it's supposed to be

Comment: It's okey, So, i have  edited the new code , the image cannot be displayed but i get new error :  `data:image/png;base64,[object Object]:1 GET data:image/png;base64,[object Object] 0 ()`